# Check Mac app installation method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

How can I check whether a Mac app was downloaded and installed from the Mac App Store or not?

I have tried to find get any clue regarding the installation process in the Application's info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existence of the App Receipt:

```
/Applications/Something.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt
```

If it exists then this app was downloaded from the Mac App Store, else it was downloaded from outside the Mac App Store.

Comment: Thanks trojan. And also it is possible to delete other Mac Applications while the our application is in the Sandbox mode.

Comment: @Rajuram89 It's possible I think yes; first the user would have to give you access to `/Applications` via a file open dialog and then you need to initialise raised privileges, but that's not something I've ever done.  It's worth searching/asking a question on this subject alone.